# Pattern matching on a tuple

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, tuples

For the condition below - in which a pattern match has been defined for a `Tuple2(BigDecimal,BigDecimal)`

```
  (r.get(0), r.get(1)) match {
    case (r0: BigDecimal, r1: BigDecimal) => (bigDecimalNullToZero(r0), bigDecimalNullToZero(r1))
    case (r0,r1)  => {
      error(s"Unable to compare [$r0] and [$r1]"); (0L,0L)
    }
  }
```

why is the match not being recognized?

[image]

[image]

Comment: @TzachZohar  The type of the r0 and r1 are shown in the second screenshot as `BigDecimal`

Comment: I can see that, I'm asking about the type of `r` - or, more accurately, the signature of `r.get`

Comment: @DanW Not sure why that would be useful: at that juncture the intended (/correct?) first match has already been bypassed

Comment: @TzachZohar  oh I see what you mean.  Yes the type is `Any` . So then the `compile` time type is used not the `runtime` type ..  I guess that makes sense..  No wait that does not .. runtime type checking is actually a v key part of pattern matching: so then why would the type `r.get(): Any` cause this?

Comment: `object TestTupleMatch extends App {
  val bd1 = BigDecimal(51302213.000000)
  val bd2 = BigDecimal(51302213.000000)

  (bd1, bd2) match {
    case (r0: BigDecimal, r1: BigDecimal) => println("matched")
    case (r0,r1)  => println("Unable to compare [$r0] and [$r1]")
  }
} ` The above program give the result matched . It means it works correctly. I use scala 2.12.4 and java 1.8.0_144

Comment: Actually - pattern matching should be able to detect that (sorry, my confusion - erasure is irrelevant here).

Comment: @javadba a quick test on my machine doesn't have the same behavior. It may be an error of the IDE debugger, can you print `r0.getClass()`?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella  You were on the right path .. I did not realize there were two `BigDecimal`'s one from the jvm and the other a scala-ism

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to assume that `r` in this case is of type `org.apache.spark.sql.Row` - if that's the case, you're simply using the **wrong BigDecimal** class - you're matching against Scala's built-in `scala.math.BigDecimal` while Spark uses `java.math.BigDecimal` under the hood.

So - if you match using Java's class this should work as expected:

```
(r.get(0), r.get(1)) match {
  case (r0: java.math.BigDecimal, r1: java.math.BigDecimal) => (bigDecimalNullToZero(r0), bigDecimalNullToZero(r1))
  case (r0,r1)  => {
    error(s"Unable to compare [$r0] and [$r1]"); (0L,0L)
  }
}
```

I used this full example to test this:

```
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  (BigDecimal(2.1), BigDecimal(2.3)) // using Scala's BigDecimal to build DF
).toDF("name", "hit_songs")

df.foreach { r: Row => (r.get(0), r.get(1)) match {
  case (s1: BigDecimal, s2: BigDecimal) => println("found Scala BigDecimals")
  case (s1: java.math.BigDecimal, s2: java.math.BigDecimal) => println("found Java BigDecimals")
  case (s1, s2) => println(s"Not found")
}}

// prints: found Java BigDecimals
```

**P.S.** You can usually simplify such "extractions" from a Row using Row's `unapply` function, i.e. matching on a `Row(a, b, ...)`:

```
df.map {
  case Row(s1: java.math.BigDecimal, s2: java.math.BigDecimal, _*) => (s1, s2)
}
```